Load balance with HAProxy and changing the host with POST data
So I am trying to load balance with HAProxy to two servers. I can get this to work without an issue. My problem is I need to change the domain if it goes to Server B. I found that you can change set-header and that works but the POST data is dropped. Below is currently where I am at. It works except as I said it drops the POST data. Hopefully I explained it well enough, just looking for some help. Thanks.
backend dl-backend
   maxconn 10000
   balance roundrobin
   server dl-backend-DO 0.0.0.0:81 weight 50 check
   server dl-backend-DL1 0.0.0.0:82 weight 50 check

listen dl-backend-DO
   bind *:81
   http-request set-header Host example.com
   server dlDO xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80 check

listen dl-backend-DL1
   bind *:82
   server dl1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80 check

